# Monitor Eufy Homebase from iPhone Apple Home?

Tags: smart-home, networking, security, apple-homekit

I have a Eufy Homebase 2 with 6 EufyCam 2C and a wired doorbell connected. The Homebase is setup as a “room” in Apple HomeKit. The Homebase is Ethernet connected to Xfinity new router, with wifi enabled as backup, in case Ethernet is unplugged. xFi app and Apple Home app are on my iPhone.

How can I get an alert on my iPhone, if the Eufy Homebase drops from the network?

Comment: Just to be clear, are do you want to get a notification *when* the Homebase has dropped from the network, or do you simply want to continue receiving notifications *even if* the Homebase Ethernet connection has failed?

Comment: I want to get a notification _when_ the Homebase drops from the network, or rather when it's no longer present _on_ the network.

Ex: if a teenager were to unplug the Homebase to sneak out, I want a push notification that it's offline ;)

Comment: I doubt you can get Homekit to do this, but you might be able to query the router e.g. with snmp to report when a MAC address goes off line

Comment: Sure. A friend also suggested pinging the devices ip and send notification when offline. He suggested a raspberry pi solution, but I might see if I can get my old iPad on the job.

Comment: @hardillb I found a few apps for iPhone which will ping the device's ip address successfully, but none of them have a "background ping" or push notifications ... looking further.